# Error building iOS project with Jenkins on MacOS X Lion

Tags: jenkins, version-control

Jenkins successfully manages to checkout the project from BitBucket but after that I get this error message:

> Started by user anonymous
>
> Building in workspace
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/myprojectAdHocBuild/workspace
>
> Checkout:workspace /
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/myprojectAdHocBuild/workspace -
>   hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@xxxxxxx
>
> Using strategy: Default
>
> Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
>
> Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myproject.git
>
> No candidate revisions
>
> ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and
>   branch configuration for this job.
>
> Archiving artifacts
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Any idea how to fix it?

My server system information:

> MacMini running MACOSX Lion 10.8.2 (fresh installed) 
>   Jenkins version
>   1.489

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] before posting a question. This is OT here.

Comment: Off-topic, meaning that this sites doesn't deal with this kind of questions.

Comment: I was thinking that configuring a Jenkins server is a topic covered by this website.Being a server.

Comment: "If your question is about…

Server and Business Workstation operating systems, hardware, software and virtualization" I don't think is so OT

Comment: @SvenW interesting.... if this question is "OT" then why "serverfault" allows tags such as "jenkins" and "revision-control" which this question is covering?

Comment: This question is borderline on topic. These types of servers are **not** always off topic, they can be production servers supporting large groups of development staff. Claus, if you could provide a bit more scope over what this system is supporting, it'll help wave off the 'this is OT' comments.

Comment: I've edited my question.Is it ok?

Comment: @Alex: [SF] allows any tag someone creates. I believe there is a certain minimum rep you need to create a tag, but this isn't a real barrier. Anyway, I read the question more as a "how do I use Jenkins" type, which I would consider OT, but it certainly can be interpreted as a "get it up and running" question as well.

Comment: Off-topic = OT, On-topic = OT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btw I've found a solution.My error was that,in the Jenkins job configuration area I included the branch to be build tag in lowercase characters when it was case-sensitive